# C#: Calling a php script and beeing able to stop it

Tags: c#, php, process

I am currently working on a C# Program which needs to call a local PHP script and write its output to a file. The problem is, that I need to be able to stop the execution of the script.

First, I tried to call cmd.exe and let cmd write the output to the file which worked fine. But I found out, that killing the cmd process does not stop the php cli.

So I tried to call php directly, redirect its output and write it from the C# code to a file. But here the problem seems to be, that **the php cli does not terminate when the script is done**. `process.WaitForExit()` does not return, even when I am sure that the script has been fully executed.

I cannot set a timeout to the `WaitForExit()`, because depending on the arguments, the script may take 3 minutes or eg. 10 hours.

I do not want to kill just a random php cli, there may be others currently running.

**What is the best way to call a local php script from C#, writing its output to a file and beeing able to stop the execution?**

Here is my current code:

```
// Create the process
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "php.exe";
// CreateExportScriptArgument returns something like "file.php arg1 arg2 ..."
process.StartInfo.Arguments = CreateExportScriptArgument(code, this.content, this.options);
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

// Start the process or cancel, if the process should not run
if (!this.isRunning) { return; }
this.currentProcess = process;
process.Start();

// Get the output
var output = process.StandardOutput;

// Wait for the process to finish
process.WaitForExit();
this.currentProcess = null;
```

To kill the process I am using:

```
// Mark as not running to prevent starting new
this.isRunning = false;

// Kill the process
if (this.currentProcess != null)
{
  this.currentProcess.Kill();
}
```

Thanks for reading!

**EDIT**

That the cli does not return seems to be not reproducible. When I test a different script (without arguments) it works, probably its the script or the passing of the arguments.

Running my script from cmd works just fine, so the script should not be the problem

**EDIT 2**

When disabling `RedirectStandardOutput`, the cli quits. could it be, that I need to read the output, before the process finishes? Or does the process wait, when some kind of buffer is full?

**EDIT 3: Problem solved**

Thanks to VolkerK, I / we found a solution. The problem was, that `WaitForExit()` did not get called, when the output is not read (probably due to a full buffer in the standard output). My script wrote much output.

What works for me:

```
process.Start();

// Get the output
var output = process.StandardOutput;

// Read the input and write to file, live to avoid reading / writing to much at once
using (var file = new StreamWriter("path\\file", false, new UTF8Encoding()))
{
    // Read each line
    while (!process.HasExited)
    {
        file.WriteLine(output.ReadLine());
    }

    // Read the rest
    file.Write(output.ReadToEnd());

    // flush to file
    file.Flush();
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the "the php cli does not terminate when the script is done." part. Thought you might have to close the standard input stream, but no, once the script was done WaitForExit() returned.

Comment: Hm, that is strange. I will look if I can change something with the input stream

Comment: I just copied your script to a new console project skeleton, removed the `this. ...` stuff and replaced the `CreateExportScriptArgument` part by `@"-f test.php"` (and yes, the script was running; I've checked `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` ;-) )

Comment: The php manual says, that the `-f` is not needed, but I will try that, too. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php)

Comment: No no, the `-f` argument makes no difference. Can you create and post simple, yet complete (and tested) "one .cs file" example?

Comment: Yup, I will do that. I just tested a different script, and it worked... maybe its the arguments

Comment: "Or does the process wait, when some kind of buffer is full?" - Most likely. You might be interested in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Great, that was the problem! I just need to read while the script is being executed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem was that the output buffer was full and therefore the php process stalled while waiting to send its output, asynchronously reading the output in the c# program is the solution.

```
class Program {
    protected static /* yeah, yeah, it's only an example */ StringBuilder output;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create the process
        var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "php.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-f path\\test.php mu b 0 0 pgsql://user:pass@x.x.x.x:5432/nominatim";
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        output = new StringBuilder();
        process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;

        // Start the process
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        // Wait for the process to finish
        process.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine("test");
        // <-- do something with Program.output here -->

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) {
            // edit: oops the new-line/carriage-return characters are not "in" e.Data.....
            // this _might_ be a problem depending on the actual output.
            output.Append(e.Data);
            output.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

see also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx